# Equivalent of a traverse in arrow notation

Tags: haskell, arrows

I'm using the [hasql](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hasql) library to interact with a PostgreSQL database and it uses Arrows for queries and query composition.

I have a simple query with this type:

```
setCustomerAttributes :: Query (TagData, UserDetails) ()
```

where `Query` is the arrow `(TagData, UserDetails)` is the input and it returns `()`.

Now I want to write a query that takes several `TagData` as input and just runs this query for all of them.
Essentially I'd want to do something like this

```
setManyCustomerAttributes :: Query ([TagPair], Customer) ()
setManyCustomerAttributes = proc (pairs, customer) -> do
  returnA -< traverse_ (\pair -> setCustomerAttribute -< (pair, customer)) pairs
```

However this of course produces the error `Arrow command found where expression was expected`, as you can't just mix and match arrow notation and regular expressions like that.

What is the arrow equivalent of doing a traverse like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need something stronger than just `Arrow` - you'll need [`ArrowChoice`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowChoice). Thankfully, `Query` is an instance of that too. You can make something work with

```
setManyCustomerAttributes :: Query ([TagData], UserDetails) ()
setManyCustomerAttributes = proc (pairs,customer) ->
        case pairs of
          [] -> returnA -< ()
          (p:ps) -> do
             setCustomerAttributes -< (p,customer)
             setManyCustomerAttributes -< (ps,customer)
```

I'm still thinking about if there is some interesting abstraction analogous to `traverse` worth generalizing here.

#### EDIT

If there is an `Arrow` equivalent, [`Traversing`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.2/docs/Data-Profunctor-Traversing.html#t:Traversing) may be a generalizing abstraction.

Comment: Deceptively simple! ^^ This works great, i was thinking too much in old tracks to really take a step back and try to do a normal case matching recursion. Thanks.